# how come acosf never return negative values for me?

Tags: c++, trigonometry

```
            xlight = cosf(angle_to_light);
            ylight = sinf(angle_to_light);
            xrotate = A*xlight;// - B*xrepel;// + C*xrandom;
            yrotate = A*ylight;// - B*yrepel;// + C*yrandom;

            angle_to_rotate = acosf( xrotate/( sqrtf(xrotate*xrotate + yrotate*yrotate) ) );
            //printf("xrotate = %f, yrotate = %f, rotate = %f\n", xrotate, yrotate, angle_to_rotate);
            if (angle_to_rotate>0) {
                set_motors(0,kilo_turn_right);
            }
            else if (angle_to_rotate<0) {
                printf("hello\n" );
                set_motors(kilo_turn_left,0);
            }
```

I never get negative value for angle_to_rotate for some reason. Basically my code never prints "hello". angle_to_light can be positive or negative in radians? how does acosf work exactly in c++?

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/acos) the `acosf` function returns values in the range [0;π].

Mathematically, arccos is a multi-valued function ; in particular, cos X == cos -X.  The C++ function can only return one representative value and they decided on that range. You can get the other values by adding 2π and/or negating .

Comment: But there is an if-else clause under acosf line that calls set_motion differently for + and - angle_of_rotation. How do I enter the else if part if angle_rotation is always positive... and some positive maybe correct also because this code snippet is constantly running in a loop with different angle_to_light values

Comment: @DhanvinKodiatar maybe you will have to determine the direction via a different method, it's a simple fact that X and -X have the same cosine

Comment: I figured it out... i can just check for my argument. Basically if (argument of acosf < 0) { angle_of_rotation = -angle_of_rotation}. Thank you for the help!!